# How to bind ComboBox SelectedItem from another DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have an edit `usercontrol`, that is used to edit Workout details.
On that UC there is a `combobox` that has its datacontext set to another viewmodel of Exercise Equipment. How can i get after opening uc to selected item gets to the property of Workout.

**Here is the code:**

```
<ComboBox Name="ExeEquComboBox" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllExerciseEquipment}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
        SelectedValue="{Binding ExerciseEquipment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.DataContext>
        <ExerciseEquipmentViewModel/>
    </ComboBox.DataContext>
</ComboBox>
```

EDIT: posting more details as requested:

Workout properties are:
Name,
Description
IdExerciseEquipment (foreign key to ExerciseEquipment table).

I have 2 ViewModels: 
WorkoutViewModel
ExerciseEquipmentViewModel

When i open the UC i pass the Workout object to it and set the datacontext of the usercontrol to that object.

On that UC there is a combobox that has its datacontext set to the ExerciseEquipmentViewModel. 
I get the itemsource from that viewmodel.

What i need is to properly bind Workout.IdExerciseEquipment to the Combobox itemsource. When opening UserControl, Combobox.SelectedItem
should be the item with Workout.IdExerciseEquipment, but i dont know how to achieve that.

Thanks.

Comment: Post more code and be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

`Ancestor Binding` like you have done. Just correct the `binidng` as below:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.ExerciseEquipment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

`Element Binding`, as below:

```
ComboBox Name="ExeEquComboBox" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllExerciseEquipment}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=UserControlName,Path=DataContext.ExerciseEquipment}">
```

**Update:** from the information you provided I'm able to understand that there is `IdExerciseEquipment` property in `Workout` object, i think this is some kind of ID for distinguish `AllExerciseEquipment` items. I think you should create your property as below in `Workout` class:

```
private string exerciseEquipment;

    public string ExerciseEquipment
    {
        get 
        {
            if (exerciseEquipment == null)
            {
                exerciseEquipment = AllExerciseEquipment.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.IdExerciseEquipment);
            }
            return exerciseEquipment;
        }
        set 
        { 
            exerciseEquipment = value; 
        }
    }
```

So by default when `ExerciseEquipment` is blank, we set a value to the item where `ID` is matched, by iterating `AllExerciseEquipment` which is your `ItemSource` of `ComboBox`.

*Since I don't have your exact class definitions please change the code where needed.*

Comment: I have tired both of your solutions and they both work. However, upon opening UserControl, there is nothing selected in the combobox. How can i make the combox show the ExerciseEquipment that has the id in the Workout.IdExerciseEquipment?

Comment: @MarkoDragičević your language is very high level and I'm not able to see your issue. As My understanding Workout is ViewModel & IdExerciseEquipment is a property of view model. Am I correct? and doesn this Workout.IdExerciseEquipment has to do with anything with your UserControl?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language :( Yes, Workout is ViewModel & IdExerciseEquipment is a property of view model.
Thing is, when i open UserControl, Combobox selectedItem should "jump" to the ExerciseEquipment of the Workout.
For example, i have a "Bench Press" workout that i want to edit. It has properties Name: "Bench Press", Description: "lorem Ipsum", IdEquipment: 17.
When i open UC, combobox should show ExerciseEquipment.Name: "Bench", but the SelectedItem is null at the moment.
Binding Works if i select something from the combobox list.

Comment: @MarkoDragičević I don't mean English pal. :) I mean you are saying this object that property etc and we don't have any idea what your class structures are. I've updated my answer based on some assumptions. please give code your all classes if want the exact fix.

Comment: Thank you :) this is what i've been missing.